# Firefox bug with dropdown borders? Bottom border not rendering in some cases

Tags: html, css, firefox

I was made aware of this bug when working with dropdown menus () in angular using ng-options.  In some cases, Firefox does not render the bottom border of a dropdown menu, almost like it shaves off a few pixels on the bottom.  If there were many menus on the page, it almost seemed to form a pattern (ABABAB | A = correct, B = incorrect). It seemed to be finicky based on font-size and browser zoom level.

I first thought it was an issue with angular, but it seemed to be more of a browser rendering/css issue.  I have found similar bug reports, but they are dated:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311770

In the stuff I am working on, the font-size is 8pt and it happens on the default zoom level.  I was able to reproduce it using angular's angular-phonecat, and in my case it happens with a font-size of 8pt and a zoom level of 1.  (If you want to reference phonecat, the only change I made was in the css, I changed the stylesheet for select font-size to 8pt and added the below to create dropdowns).

```
<!-- Generates multiple populated dropdowns easily -->
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <td>
            <select ng-model = "phones" ng-options="phone.id for phones in phones">
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is the an example of an incorrect one and a correct one.
[image: Bugged view vs correct one]

I also reproduced this issue without using ng-options, and its the same case, the following code produces the same issue if repeated multiple times:

```
<select>
        <option value=""></option>  <!-- mimics default value produced by ng-options -->
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">A</option>
    </select>
```

After further investigation, I found I was able to fix it by inserting an option with a non-breaking space that forces the default empty value to be of an equal height to the others like the following code snippet I used to reproduce it in angular-phonecat (though this doesn't explain why some rendered fine and others didn't):

```
<!-- Generates multiple populated dropdowns easily -->
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <td>
            <select ng-model = "phones" ng-options="phone.id for phones in phones">
            <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For easy access, here is a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/f3mzm/
For me, on 1920x1080, the group of dropdown menus have no bottom-border, but re-sizing the browser window to certain sizes has them.
[image: Issue in JSfiddle]

The kicker is this: I already mentioned that if I make the first option a non-breaking space it worked, but if I changed the font-size to something other than 8pt, it works fine as well.  The latter is not an option with what I am working on and the former is unfavorable, but seems like its needed as a workaround.  Is this indeed a browser issue like the other border issues that have been reported about the browser, or am I just going insane?

Comment: Can you produce a jsFiddle?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to do that.  I have updated my question with a successful reproduction of the issue on my box.

Comment: Can't really reproduce the issue. Do you have specific zoom levels in mind? Also, which OS and FF version? v24.0 here on Windows 7 (WOW64).

Comment: For the fiddle, it happens for me on 1920x1080 resolution with default zoom.  Firefox v24.0, and Win7Pro x64
For the phonecat it happens with an increase in zoom of 1 (ctrl + mousewheel up)

It is the strangest issue that I am trying to diagnose, but to no avail.

Comment: Figured out the issue a few weeks ago, figure I should post it here if anyone else having the issue:  Define option in your CSS such that it has the same height as you intend.